# Calculate the mean of files generated from gdal.Translate

Tags: gdal, raster-calculator, gdal-translate

I created several velocity maps from .nc files through `gdal.Translate`. Each .nc file is organized in several bands, I am only interested in 1: velocities. `gdal.Translate` allows me to select only the velocities and cut them to my area of interest.

I would like to calculate the velocities' mean on a specific time-period, and for that I intended to open on Python my cut files (.vrt). However, when I open them in Python they are all "NoneType", while when I open them in QGIS I can see the velocities.

To calculate the means, my idea was to use:

```
myarray = np.array(ds.ReadAsArray())
```

Where `ds` is my cut velocity map. Then in a loop, I stack the `myarray` in a 3D matrix, and calculate the mean over the time axis.

Do you know if there is a better way to do it? Also, why do I have only NoneType files? I am new to gdal, and I am surprised QGIS can recognize my cut velocities maps while Python sees only a NoneType. I could calculate the mean through Raster Calculator in QGIS, but I want to automatize this task.

Ps: this is how I open my .nc file, cut and select the velocities only:

```
ds = gdal.Open("NETCDF:{0}:{1}".format(netcdf_name, layer_name))
gdal.Translate('output/' + Name + '.vrt', ds, projWin = [-3353315, 380000, -3257001, 260460])
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python package `osgeo.gdal` is not really "Pythonic", so there are several quirks and [gotchas](https://gdal.org/api/python_gotchas.html) to be aware of.

The NoneType returned from Open means that the file could not be opened. Here's a quick demo:

```
from osgeo import gdal

ds = gdal.Open("NETCDF:file.nc:velocity")
# you may see the following message in a console:
# ERROR 4: `NETCDF:file.nc:velocity' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
print(ds)  # None

gdal.UseExceptions()
ds = gdal.Open("NETCDF:file.nc:velocity")
RuntimeError: `NETCDF:file.nc:velocity' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
```

By setting `gdal.UseExceptions()`, the above throws `RuntimeError` if the dataset cannot be opened.

An alternative GDAL-based package is [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/).

```
import rasterio

with rasterio.open("NETCDF:file.nc:velocity", "r") as ds:
    ar = ds.read()
```

which will usually raise useful errors, where appropriate.

---

As for the other part of the question to process netCDF files, I've found [NCO](http://nco.sourceforge.net/) tools to be the best. They are not easy to use, but there is extensive documentation and examples on how to use them. They can be used to calculate averages of time-varying variables in an efficient manner. The result could possibly be viewed directly or post-processed and re-projected to a different GIS format.

Comment: Look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796170/calculating-monthly-mean-from-daily-netcdf-file-in-python, which uses xarray to solve a similar problem.